# How to convert pictures formats using linux convert command?

Tags: linux, image, shell, command-line, type-conversion

How is the correct way to use `-format` option into `convert command`?

I want to convert an image: "amazing_eagle.jpg" to `eps` format, with the same `file name`, this is using the option `-format`.

I try the command:

```
convert -​format eps ​amazing_eagle.jpg
```

and I get the following error:

```
convert.im6: no images defined `amazing_eagle.jpg '@ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

Note: the file is in the folder where I run this command

Answer (score 0):

```
magick amazing_eagle.jpg -​format eps amazing_eagle.eps
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/5bc61bf/misc/mosaic.sh#L67-L68)